# Python - convert number to exponential

Tags: python

How can i convert an array like this:

```
[ 76809102.22  38393173.33    -17066.67 -48000000.           0.           0.   -28809102.22 -38393173.33    -17066.67]
```

to exponential?

```
[  7.68091022e+07   3.83931733e+07  -1.70666700e+04  -4.80000000e+07   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -2.88091022e+07  -3.83931733e+07  -1.70666700e+04]
```

I have been trying many thing and just get error!

Comment: In the future, it helps to include __what__ you have tried and __what errors__ you actually got, as well as a full traceback. "I keep trying stuff and it doesn't work" is a great complaint, but a horrible problem description if your goal is to get help from strangers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is a NumPy array, then you could use

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.8e}'.format})
```

to [change the way floats are displayed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([76809102.22, 38393173.33, -17066.67, -48000000., 0., 0., -28809102.22, 
              -38393173.33, -17066.67])
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.8e}'.format})
print(x)
```

yields

```
[ 7.68091022e+07  3.83931733e+07 -1.70666700e+04 -4.80000000e+07
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -2.88091022e+07 -3.83931733e+07
 -1.70666700e+04]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *e* format for representing a decimal number with exponential notation:

```
'{:e}'.format(1.0)
'1.000000e+00'
```